# How to import a TypeScript file as a library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a personal "library" that I made that I call methlib, and I have it stored as a .ts file on my computer. Inside it tons of classes, interfaces, functions, etc. that I use a bunch and I like to just have in one place. Now my problem is I want to use the functions and stuff from there in another project that I have that I am making in typescript (as one would usually want to do with a library) but I don't know how. Before I had translated it into typescript I could just include it in the HTML file (usually by just going up into my main web directory and grabbing the local file so that if I made any changes to it it would take effect immediately) but now I don't know what to do. I am also not very familiar (at all) with any of the terminology and I am very new to typescript and more advanced javascript or web development at all. Now when I try to grab something from my library like

```
import { Collider } from "Methlib/methlib"
```

with my webpack config (which I mostly stole from a template and don't fully understand) set up like

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/script.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"],
        alias: {
            Methlib: "./../Methlib-js/"
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
    }
}
```

with a file structure like

```
<root>
 | Methlib-js
 | | methlib.ts
 | <project folder>
 | | node_modules
 | | src
 | | | script.ts
 | | webpack.config.js
 | | package.json
 | | package-lock.json
```

running `>node_modules\.bin\webpack` gives me

```
ERROR in <root>\<project folder>\src\script.ts
./src/script.ts
[tsl] ERROR in <root>\<project folder>\src\script.ts(5,26)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'Methlib/methlib' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Also please mind the whole  and  thing, it's just so that I don't have to reveal my exact file structure where it isn't completely necessary. I would like to clarify that  isn't actually part of the project, just the root of my file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the full absolute path to the library in the webpack.config.js file, and upon further testing it would seem that you don't even need to include the path mapping in the tsconfig.json file either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) for ts as well:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "Methlib": ["../Methlib-js/methlib.ts"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CharmingGiftedModule)

Comment: But isn't that for a tsconfig.json file and not a webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Yes, you need both (ts does its own resolving as well)

Comment: I didn't know that it was included, in any case I still had it in there
`"baseUrl": "./../", "paths": {"Methlib": ["Methlib-js"]}` (condensed to one line for formatting)

Comment: @lightningund, Apparently in this scenario you need to specify the full path (and then import the module without the extension).

Comment: specify the full path in the tsconfig or the webpack config?

Comment: the tsconfig (like the edit) and then `import { Collider } from "Methlib"`